# is my proof of the fact that every real number can be represented by a decimal expansion correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, number-systems

assume that S is a set of real numbers that don't have a decimal expansion.
If S is not empty, then it must have a least element r according to the well-ordering principle.
r can be expressed as the sum of two smaller real numbers n and m.
Since n and m are smaller than r, they are not a part of S. So they have a decimal expansion.
the sum of their decimal expansion is also a decimal expansion that is equal to r.
This is a contradiction. Therefore S is empty.

Comment: What ordering are you using for the least element of $S$? The reals aren't well-ordered in the standard ordering.

Comment: The Well-Ordering Principle is about natural numbers. For example, $(0,1)$ has no least element. You probably meant the Upper Bound Property, which applies to non-empty subsets of $\mathbb R$ that are **bounded above**: every nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$ that is bounded above (resp. bounded below) has a least upper bound (resp. a largest lower bound).

Comment: Besides that, your proof is correct to me. You may have to explain why the sum of two real numbers having a decimal expansion also has a decimal expansion tough. Instead, you may consider $r-1$ instead of $m$ and $n$ to simplify the reasoning a bit.

Comment: What's your definition of a real number?

Comment: The reals only have the well-ordering principal if we accept the axiom of choice.  And if we do accept the axiom of choice and the well ordering principal no mathematician has ever been able to demonstrate and an order by which the reals are well ordered.  If we accept that the reals have such an order (even though we have no idea what it is) we'd have no justification that the smallest element of $S$ is the sum of two smaller elements.  For all we know $r$ might be the smallest real number.  Or all the smaller real numbers are bigger than $\frac 12 r$.

Comment: After all..... Let $M = \{$ all real numbers that are the sum of two other smaller numbers$\}$ it must have a smallest element $k$.  So there exist $j, h < k$ so that $j + h = k$.  But $j,h< k$ so neither $j, h$ are the sum of two smaller reals.  So *if* the reals are well ordered then there *MUST* exist at least two real numbers that are *not* sums of two smaller numbers.  How do we know $r$ isn't one of those numbers.

Comment: I had a professor who used to say "THe axiom of choice is obviously true.  And Zorn's Lemma is obviously false."  He was being somewhat facetious, of course (he knew darned well, AoC and ZL are equivalent), but he did point out the idea of the reals being well-ordered would be mind-boggling weird.

Answer (score 1):

As @nickf points out, any ordering of the reals which makes it well ordered is not the standard ordering. In which case your claim that $r$ must be the sum of two smaller numbers that are representable must be using "smaller" in the sense of this non-standard ordering. And that's not obvious to me; you need to prove it.

Comment: I am going to butt in and add-- that as we do not know what the ordering for the reals is that would make them well-ordered (and when I say we don't know, if mean that, no mathematician has ever demonstrated a well ordering of the reals) and for all we know but that ordering $r$ might be the smallest real number.  Or it could be that all $k \not \in S$ are so that $k > \frac 12 r$.  I seriously doubt that the claim that $r$ is the sum of two smaller *can* be proven.